# What is the best way to pass a command alias/function without reducing the functionality of said command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have an function `ll` that currently expands into this:

```
function ll () 
{ 
    ls -lh --color "$@" | grep "^d";
    ls -lh --color "$@" | grep "^-" | grep -v "~";
    ls -lh --color "$@" | grep "^l"
}
```

What this does is sort the listed folder into showing directories first, then files, then links. However, I find that such approach reduces the functionality of the `ls` command, for instance if I try to call `ll /bin /tmp`, I will get a mix of files from both folders.

Is there a general rule of thumb to pass command aliases/functions such that full functionality of those commands is not reduced? If there isn't, how can I fix my `ll` command so that I retain the sorting, but full functionality of `ls` is not lost?

Please note that I currently have bash version 3.2.25(1)-release on my system (ls version 5.97), so `--show-directories-first` flag is not available to me.

**EDIT:**

This is the function I ended up using, I modified it slightly so that `ll` would work without any args:

```
function ll () {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then set -- .; fi
  for d; do
    ls -lh --color "$d"|awk '$1~/^d/{i=0} $1~/^l/{i=1} $1~/^-/{i=2} NF>2{print i OFS $0}' | sort -n -k1,1 | cut -d ' ' -f2-
  done
}
```

Comment: To start, all your functions and aliases should be correct in all of the circumstances you will use them. Otherwise, go back and fix them, make them simpler, or split them into 2 different aliases :)

Comment: The version of `bash` you have is irrelevant; the version of `ls` you have is.

Comment: `if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then set -- .; fi;  for d; do etc; done`. What you have will have trouble with embedded spaces.

Comment: @jthill How so? Could you give an example?

Comment: mkdir "space here"; ll "space here"

Comment: @jthill Much appreciated, updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending from answer of @chepner:

Instead of running `ls` multiple times with `grep` I think it can be combined in a single command with awk, sort, cut and get the same output (directories first then files and then links):

```
function ll () { 
    for d in "$@"; do
        ls -lh --color "$d"|awk '$1~/^d/{i=0} $1~/^l/{i=1} $1~/^-/{i=2} NF>2{print i OFS $0}'|sort -n -k1,1|cut -d ' ' -f2-
    done
}
```

Comment: This is the approach I ended up using, because I liked the idea of only calling `ls` once. I will accept this as the correct answer if you correct your last command to `cut -d ' ' -f2-`, otherwise it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Handle each argument to `ll` separately:

```
function ll () 
{ 
    for d in "$@"; do
        ls -lh --color "$d" | grep "^d";
        ls -lh --color "$d" | grep "^-" | grep -v "~";
        ls -lh --color "$d" | grep "^l"
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this variation:

```
function ll { 
    local FILES=() OPTIONS=() A

    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
        case "$1" in
        --)
            FILES+=("${@:2}")
            break
            ;;
        -*)
            OPTIONS+=("$1")
            ;;
        *)
            FILES+=("$1")
            ;;
        esac
        shift
    done

    local -i FILES_COUNT=${#FILES[@]} I

    for (( I = 0; I < FILES_COUNT; ++I )); do
        A=${FILES[I]}
        [[ I -gt 0 ]] && echo
        [[ FILES_COUNT -gt 1 && -d $A/. ]] && echo "${A}:"
        # ls -lh --color "${OPTIONS[@]}" -- "$A" | grep "^total "
        ls -lh --color "${OPTIONS[@]}" -- "$A" | grep "^d";
        ls -lh --color "${OPTIONS[@]}" -- "$A" | grep "^-" | grep -v "~";
        ls -lh --color "${OPTIONS[@]}" -- "$A" | grep "^l"
    done
}
```

It somehow still tries to separate the directories when multiple arguments are passed in a way similar to the behaviour of `ls`. And it would also filter added options.